# Why getSelectedRow() in the same class gives the correct value but in a different class it gives a -1 instead even though a row is selected?

Tags: java, swing

Why is it that when i call `getSelectedRow()` in the same class it returns the correct value, but when i try to call the method from another class it returns -1 instead even though a row is selected?

For example, i have a method like this.

```
    public int getSelectedRow(){
        int row = drinksTable.getSelectedRow();
        System.out.println(row);
        return row;
    }
```

I have a jframe class **A** and a class **B** which contains all the functions such as purchase, delete, edit etc. I need to know which row is selected in order to for me to purchase, delete, edit the correct record. The above code is in the **A** class. The problem is, if i try to call the above method in the **B** class, the row returned is always -1, which means no row is selected, even though it clearly shows in the table that a row is highlighted and selected. And if i try to call the method in the same class, it returns the correct value. What is the problem here?

For example, class **A** here is called VendingMachine. I have a method like this in class **B**. The part where i used the method is in the upper half where the declaration happens. Since i wanted the value to change based on the row selected, the `selectedRow` goes inside `getValueAt(selectedRow, 1)` like so.

```
   public static void purchaseDrink(String editTerm, String oldAmount, String newAmount, String filepath){
        VendingMachine vm = new VendingMachine();
        int selectedRow = vm.getSelectedRow();
        String tempFile = "temp.txt";
        File oldFile = new File(filepath);
        File newFile = new File(tempFile);
        String drinkName = vm.model.getValueAt(selectedRow, 1).toString();
        String price = vm.model.getValueAt(selectedRow, 2).toString();
        String drinkQuantity = vm.model.getValueAt(selectedRow, 3).toString();
        String line;

        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile, true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("drinks.txt"));

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                if (drinkName.equals(editTerm)) {
                   line = line.replace(oldAmount, newAmount);
                   pw.println(line);
               } else {
                   pw.println(line);
                   System.out.println(selectedRow);
               }               
            }

            br.close();
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            oldFile.delete();
            File dump = new File(filepath);
            newFile.renameTo(dump);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to edit", "Edit failed", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Class A = VendingMachine

Class B = Drinks

So i googled abit and found out how to pass an object of class A to class B, and did it with the code below.

```
    private VendingMachine vm;
    public Drinks(VendingMachine vm) {
        this.vm = vm;
    }
```

and then invoking the method in a button like so:

```
   VendingMachine vm = new VendingMachine();
   Drinks drinks = new Drinks(vm);
   drinks.purchaseDrink(...);
```

But the `selectedRow()` method still returns a -1 instead of the row selected. What am i missing??

Comment: you can upload the complete code in github

Comment: sorry, is the question too vague?

Comment: can you upload the code in github?

Comment: @AlejandroGonzalez: that's not the point of SO, questions here should be self-contained. If you want to make yourself extra work, feel free, but please don't encourage this on SO.

Comment: @kian: we'll need more info: how do you get hold of an instance of class A in class B? Anyway, you'll need to show us more code.

Comment: If you get different results then you are invoking the getSelectedRow() method on a different instance of the class. So you need to make sure you don't have two instances of the component.

Comment: @JoachimSauer i edited the post, can you point out where did i go wrong in my code?

Comment: @camickr can you show me where i go wrong in the code? sorry i am new to java.

Comment: @kian: it's as camickr thought: you're calling `getSelectedRow()` on a **new** instance of `VendingMachine`. That's not the one that's currently being displayed. You need to somehow pass the `VendingMachine` instance that is shown to the code that needs it (as a parameter, or during construction).

Comment: @JoachimSauer may i have a bit of guidance on this? do i create the instance in the method first and then call it afterwards so the instance is the one being displayed?

Comment: @kian You should not be using static methods. The whole structure of your code is wrong. There is nothing we can do to help. You need to restructure you entire code. So my suggestion is to start over. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use LIsts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). Download the "ListDemo" code and test it and understand how it works so that you can reference the JList in an ActionListener. Then modify the working code to meet your requirement. That is start with working code and make changes.

Comment: @camickr can you tell me why shouldn't i use static methods so i wouldn't make the same mistake again? i understand that we use it when there is a need to invoke the method without creating the object, but what about in this case? or any other examples? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I can't explain in a comment. Look at the tutorial code as I suggested. Generally a GUI is designed to respond to user events like clicking a button. So I'm guessing your "Purchase a Drink", when the user clicks a buttons. So you need to add an ActionLIstener to the button. You want the code in the ActionLIstener to be able to access all the variable of your class, like the JTable to do something with the selected item. You learn from experience when a method should be static. I don't know the context of your entire code, but I suggest is should not be static.

Comment: Read other sections in the tutorial. Download other demo code and see if they use static methods.

Comment: @camickr hello, i edited my post and changed my method to a non-static one and tried to pass the instance of object that is currently shown to the other class instead of creating a new one like i did before, but the method still returns a -1, can you correct my code?

Comment: I can't possibly guess what you code is doing based on the code provided. You have been given a link to a working example. Start with a working example and make change. That is forget about your application and learn the "concept" first. Post a proper [mre] if you need help.